# Script Not Changing Based On Year or Type of Stats Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

`https://www.eastvanbaseball.com/statistics/leaders` The dropdown menus should change the year and type of stats, but it's not working. I have tried updating the script and inspecting the website to understand the errors, but I am a little out of my wheelhouse here.

The script is supposed to take JSON data from season stats and show league leaders in various statistical categories for batting and pitching.

Here is the relevant HTML and script:

```js
// Here is the javascript where I think the issue lies:


  var m,
    pushStat,
    z,
    count,
    assignTeam,
    getYear = 2023,
    statsFile = "/assets/stats/EVBL-stats-" + getYear + ".json?nocache=" + new Date().getTime(),
    teamNameData = [{
        fullName: "East Van Black Sox",
        lastName: "Black Sox",
        abbr: "SOX",
        logoPath: "Black_Sox.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Little Mtn Blasters",
        lastName: "Blasters",
        abbr: "LM",
        logoPath: "blasters.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Clark Park Brawlers",
        lastName: "Brawlers",
        abbr: "CP",
        logoPath: "brawlers.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Chinatown Cobras",
        lastName: "Cobras",
        abbr: "CHN",
        logoPath: "Cobras.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Sunrise Cosmos",
        lastName: "Cosmos",
        abbr: "COS",
        logoPath: "cosmos.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Gastown Gaolers",
        lastName: "Gaolers",
        abbr: "GAS",
        logoPath: "Gaolers.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Vancouver Isotopes",
        lastName: "Isotopes",
        abbr: "VAN",
        logoPath: "isotopes.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Mt Pleasant Murder",
        lastName: "Murder",
        abbr: "MT",
        logoPath: "Murder.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Railtown Spikers",
        lastName: "Spikers",
        abbr: "RT",
        logoPath: "Spikers_alt.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Strathcona Stevedores",
        lastName: "Stevedores",
        abbr: "STR",
        logoPath: "Stevedores.png"
      },
      {
        fullName: "Sunset Stilettos",
        lastName: "Stilettos",
        abbr: "SET",
        logoPath: "Stilettos.png"
      },
    ],
    logoRootURL = "/assets/team_logos/",
    battingStatsTabs = [20, 11, 12, 28, 23, 22, 21, 9, 10],
    pitchingStatsTabs = [69, 67, 70, 54, 57, 59, 101, 99],
    tablelength = 15,
    qualifyPA = 0,
    qualifyBF = 0,
    batHeaderLine = [],
    pitchHeaderLine = [],
    batNameTable = [],
    pitchNameTable = [],
    batTeamTable = [],
    pitchTeamTable = [],
    batStatTable = [],
    pitchStatTable = [],
    playerPA = [],
    playerBF = [],
    batTableHtmlMobile = "",
    pitchTableHtmlMobile = "",
    batHtml = '<div id="batting_leaders"><h3>BATTING LEADERS</h3>',
    pitchHtml = '<div id="pitching_leaders"><h3>PITCHING LEADERS</h3>',
    batHtmlMobile = '<div id="batting_leadersMobile"><h3>BATTING LEADERS</h3><div id="bat_tabs">',
    pitchHtmlMobile = '<div id="pitching_leadersMobile"><h3>PITCHING LEADERS</h3><div id="pitch_tabs">',
    batTabsHtml = "<ul>",
    pitchTabsHtml = "<ul>";
```

```html
<div class="selectGroupWrapper">
  <div class="selectGroupList">
    <select id="selectStatsYear">
      <option value='2023' selected>2023</option>
      <option value='2022'>2022</option>
      <option value='2019'>2019</option>
      <option value='2018'>2018</option>
      <option value='2017'>2017</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="selectGroupList">
    <select id="selectStatsType">
      <option value='regular' selected>Regular Season</option>
      <option value='playoffs'>Postseason</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="leadersTableMobile">
  <h4>Processing Stats...</h4>
</div>
<div id="leadersTable">
  <h4>Processing Stats...</h4>
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("selectStatsYear").addEventListener("change", fetchAndDisplayStats);
</script>
<script src="https://eastvanbaseball.squarespace.com/scripts/league_leaders_v2_min.js?version=0"></script>
```

Comment: Please look in the console of your page and see there are several errors. Like `fetchAndDisplayStats is not defined`

Comment: Thank you! I'll read up on changing it from Ajax. 

I am receiving two errors - 1. you have already noted, re: fetchAndDisplay

Here they are: 

Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchAndDisplayStats is not defined
    at leaders:569:79
league_leaders_v2_min.js?version=0:1 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lastName')
    at Object.<anonymous> (league_leaders_v2_min.js?version=0:1:2291)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2:27457)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2:27735)
    at league_leaders_v2_min.js?version=0:1:1976

Thanks again!

Comment: I would think the fetchAndDisplayStats is PRETTY important according to your description of the issue. Also it is likely the reason for the other error.